# Odoo: Create Invoice button disappeared in Sales Orders

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I have inherited the sale.order view, removed a couple of fields i don't need, and added my own, but now when i confirm the quotation, the Create Invoice button doesn't show up as it used to be with the original module,here's my code

```
class SalesOrderInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    product_ids = fields.One2many("product.sale.line", "sale_id", string="Products", required=False, )
    total_amount = fields.Float(string='Total', store=True, readonly=True,)

class ProductSaleLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'product.sale.line'
    _description = 'Product Sale Line'
    sale_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order', string='Offer ID', )
    product_id = fields.Many2one('custom.product', string="Product", required=True, )
    qty = fields.Integer(string='Ordered Quantity', required=True, )
    brand_id = fields.Many2one('custom.brand', related='product_id.brand_id', required=True, )
    country_id = fields.Many2one('custom.country', related='product_id.country_id', required=True, )
    sell_price = fields.Float('Price', related='product_id.sell_price', required=True, )
    price_subtotal = fields.Float(string='Subtotal', readonly=True, store=True)
```

```
            <field name="order_line" position="replace">
                <field name="product_ids"/>
            </field>
            <field name="amount_total" position="replace">
                <field name="total_amount" nolabel="1" class="oe_subtotal_footer_separator"/>
            </field>
            <xpath expr="//page[@name='other_information']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//page[2]" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='note']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='validity_date']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_invoice_id']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_shipping_id']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_invoice_id']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='sale_order_template_id']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='amount_tax']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='amount_untaxed']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Can you please update your inherited view of sale.order model in this question? In your current code it is not identified that action is proper passed or not.

Comment: stackoverflow won't let me put all my code, so here's a link to it https://pastebin.com/E0AxQM8L

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. Replace below code part in your module and test.

```
<xpath expr="//notebook/page[1]" position="replace">
    <field name="order_line">
        <field name="product_ids" mode="tree">
            <tree editable="bottom">
                <control>
                    <create string="Add a product"/>
                </control>
                <field name="product_id"/>
                <field name="brand_id"/>
                <field name="country_id"/>
                <field name="sell_price"/>
                <field name="qty"/>
                <field name="price_subtotal"/>
                <field name="sale_id" invisible="1"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </field>
</xpath>
```

Comment: it didn't work, i got an error
TypeError: record.fieldsInfo[this.viewType][fieldName] is undefined

http://127.0.0.1:8069/web/content/815-a759e4c/web.assets_backend.js:1585